# is dronekit-python api only for Mavproxy?

Tags: dronekit-python

This is the website of dronekit-python api.
http://python.dronekit.io/

I checked the examples and also online git repo, it seems all examples are built on top of mavproxy. and API itself doesn't have mavlink communication capability.

I wonder if there are any other use cases for droneapi.
and if I don't want to use mavproxy, does it mean I have to write my own mavlink layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the current release implementation (1.x) everything is built on MAVProxy.

I understand that the intention is that in future you will not necessarily have to run your apps from within a MAVProxy console (I don't know if the actual dependency on MAVProxy is being removed - I supsect not!)

Comment: This is no longer the case with the release of DroneKit Python 2. See [their migration guide for details](http://python.dronekit.io/guide/migrating.html)

Answer (score 1):

starting with v2 of dronekit-python we are MAVProxy free, please follow the migration guides http://python.dronekit.io/guide/migrating.html

Answer (score 0):

dronekit-python doesn't need to run in mavproxy.  You could use a custom mavlink communication layer to implement the API if you wanted.

(I find the implementation as a mavproxy module a little suboptimal for users in that it can be a bit confusing and a little bit weirder to write code that uses the API, but it does have the advantages of allowing the use of other mavproxy modules (maps, joystick control, whatever) along with basic mavproxy functionality like forwarding, and it can also be a faster path for development: It's probably easier to connect dronekit-python to mavproxy than to write a brand new, untested communication layer that does 50% of what mavproxy does.  I'm guilty of doing the same thing to get something working fast.)

Comment: what you are describing here is dividing mavproxy into core and "extra" functionality, which is in active development right now on mavproxy