# Debugging options /Dronekit outside of Mavproxy

Tags: dronekit-python

I would be very interested to know more about running Dronekit outside of Mavproxy. I'm developing a large app at the moment, which is mostly decision making logic and 'health' checking of the flight. Debugging is fairly important, and is difficult to do in Mavproxy/Dronekit.

Running Dronekit independently of Mavproxy would allow for easier debugging through IDEs like PyCharm. At the moment, I'm using pymavlink instead of Dronekit for this reason. I would love to switch, so it would be nice to hear thoughts and time frames for future plans.

A second question: can you share any insights or methods used for debugging in the current version of Dronekit?

Comment: DroneKit-Python is a MAVProxy module, that said there are plans on MAVProxy to create a core lib.

Comment: re debug: It would depend on what do you want to debug and how do you want to enter this debugging session

Comment: for starters, it would be nice to insert things like breakpoints, just to be able to examine the code state. also, having a really clean way to stop and start scripts without too much work in mavproxy would be nice.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968265/is-dronekit-python-api-only-for-mavproxy/30029016

Answer (score 0):

You can debug using pdb, which allows you to create breakpoints etc.

The documentation has now been updated with a [debugging g](http://python.dronekit.io/guide/debugging.html)uide which covers the topic "state of play".